# How to change value of EIP in ollydbg?

Tags: ollydbg

I double clicked on `EIP` in register window,but seems un-editable.

Why is `EIP` special?How can I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Find the location you want to set your EIP to, right click and select "New Origin Here". This will reset the EIP to the new address. You can confirm this by inspecting the registers at the top right.

In addition to the reply above, the EIP is basically the pointer to where the current line of execution is. It's used to keep a record of which instruction the program is executing in memory.

Answer (score 4):

press `Ctrl+g` and type the value of `EIP` and press enter.

press `Ctrl + *` to set `EIP`.

The `EIP` register always contains the address of the next instruction to be executed.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful if you want to set EIP to an address that OllyDbg thinks is data (e.g. after injecting some code to the process)